# Smarter removing objects with many-to-many relationship in Django admin interface

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'd like to remove some object with many-to-many relationship using Django admin interface. Standard removing also removes all related objects and the list of removed objects displayed on confirmation page. But I don't need to remove related objects!

Assume we have ContentTopic and ContentItem:

```
class ContentTopic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    code = models.CharField()

class ContentItem(models.Model):
    topic = models.ManyToManyField(ContentTopic, db_index=True,\
    blank=True, related_name='content_item')
```

So, I'd like to remove ContentTopic instance using Django admin, but I don't need remove all related ContentItems. So, confirmation page should display only ContentTopic instance to remove.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens so, coz its developed to do so.
If you want to change this behaviour, the one way can be over-riding delete method of `django.db.models.Model`.

This `delete()` method actually does two things, first gathering a list of all dependent objects and delete them. So here, you can override it, to get that list of dependent objects, iterating over it and set their reference to `None`, instead of deleting them. And thus deleting the concerned object cleanly.

May be if you want this behavior throughout, you can extend a class from `django.db.models.Models`, override `delete()`, and extend all your models from this new class.